# CMake call add_subdirectory within custom command

Tags: cmake, dependencies

I'm working with a code generator that produces C++ and a CMakeLists.txt file, unfortunately I cannot use this in my main CMakeLists.txt file for testing purposes.

For example you have the following CMakeLists.txt file:

```
project(SomeProject CXX C)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${SRCS}
    COMMAND ${CODEGEN_CLI_PATH} -i "${INPUT}" -o "${OUT}"
    COMMENT "Generating sources"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    VERBATIM
)

add_custom_target(CODEGEN
    DEPENDS
    ${SRCS}
)

# Needs to be executed after the custom command
add_subdirectory(${GENERATED_CMAKE_LISTS_LOCATION})
```

Is it possible to use functions such as `add_subdirectory` only after you execute custom commands for a particular target, such as `CODEGEN`?

I've already tried to execute it by adding an extra line to the existing custom command:

```
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -D DIR=${GENERATED_CMAKE_LISTS_LOCATION} -P add_subdirectories.cmake
```

Unfortuantly this doesn't work because it isn't allowed to execute functions like `add_subdirectory` in script mode.

Neither I can manage to call custom made functions (that are executing `add_subdirectory`) from `add_custom_command` that are located in the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it is not possible. The `add_subdirectory` command is run during configuration step, while `CODEGEN` is a target that runs during build.

You seem to be doing something wrong, so the only advice I can give you is to use `execute_process` command to run commands you need. The `execute_process` command is executed during configuration stage, so it will be able to generate files you need before `add_subdirectory`.

But again, please describe your problem, why do you want CMake to do that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - To clarify your question, it's the only way to proper test the generated code with Google Test and have it working within a CI/CD environment. I need to have the depending libs available when linking it with the test executable.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the `execute_process` cost me some amount of hair pulling because this thing seems to run asynchronously. That means, it seems to run in parallel. Are you sure that `execute_process` is a good construct for expressing dependency?

Comment: @typelogic In parallel with what?

Answer (score 0):

I have a huge fixed unsigned char array that I compiled into a static library. The way I work around it is by:

```
if(NOT EXISTS ${PATH_TO_FOLDER}/smeagol.a)
    add_subdirectory(smeagol)
endif()
```

I'm still looking for a nicer kung-fu way to do it using cmake. I feel that its out there, and I will update this answer once i find it.

Comment: Some sort of parallelization hapenning inside cmake